# HttpContext.User.Identity.Name always returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the B2C ID Provider. The authentication part in my app is working correctly. However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to retrieve information about the logged-in user. The HttpContext.User.Identity is consistently returning null.

[image]

My launchSettings

[image]

The problem

[image]

I saw in other questions here and the solution was stuffs in relation of the AnonymusAcess, but I changed it and continues with the problem...

Comment: What status code are you getting?  200 OK means ID Provider isn't finding the item and returning with null.  If you are getting another status that you need to post the status being returned.

Comment: Indeed, it is returning a token, but it doesn't contain the 'Name' information. I don't believe it's an issue with the token retrieval itself; perhaps there's a misconfiguration either in my code or in the Azure settings.

Comment: Can you please attach the code of the endpoint so that I can see the method signature and body? Code snippets are always better than screenshots.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem.

[image]

I didn't enabled some options in my claims. I resolved in the page that my image shows